# Lusca csp error with regards to jquery

Tags: node.js, express, content-security-policy

I am trying to implement the lusca csp policy. My application runs on express v4+ and node.js. . My lusca policy is as

```
 app.use(lusca({
csp: {
    policy:{
        'default-src':'\'self\'',
        'script-src':"'self' maps.googleapis.com maps.gstatic.com",
        'img-src':'\'self\'',
        'frame-ancestors':'\'self\'',
        'style-src': "'self'"
    }
},
xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN'      
}));
```

The issue is that when the page loads I get the following error

jquery.js:5741 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I have tried adding sha to 'script-src' but it does not seem to solve the issue. Am I missing out on any particular issue?

Comment: Why are you changing `script-src` when the error clearly states the issue is with `style-src`?

Comment: Hi Anand,as mentioned in the question, I had made changes to the script-src. I Still get the same error. My script-src value is as "style-src": "'self' sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE="

Comment: Managed to get it to work. added a single quotes around the sha-256. It is now "style-src": "'self' 'sha256-1PxuDsPyGK6n+LZsMv0gG4lMX3i3XigG6h0CzPIjwrE='"